# Microsoft Access - get record id when button is clicked

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using access to create a form.

i was wondering how to i get the current record id when i click a button.
I tried "Me.CurrentRecord" in the vb button code. but this done not work.
Can anyone help ?

```
Private Sub save_record_Enter()

Me.CurrentRecord

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the schema of your table? Do you have a field called ID?

Comment: No i am using access so i was wondering is there a function you can use to get the current record number of the form

Comment: It depends on what you mean by current record. I can tell you that the current record is the fifth record down when I sort by date, but I very much doubt that is what you want. In a relational database, there is no such thing as current record number. There is the position with in a sort order, and, if you have set up your tables properly, there is a unique ID. Say what it is you want to do, and you will get an answer.

Comment: Actually, Derek, I think you're there.  You want to perform a save function on me.currentrecord?  Try checking intellisence (hit the .) after currentrecord.

Comment: yes it would be the unique id number named "ID".

Comment: The default action for MS Access is to save a record, for the most part, it takes a bit of effort to **not** save. If you want to ensure that a record is saved at a particular point, you can use `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty=false` It is usually best not to give the impression you are saving unless you have done something to stop the default action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to fields in the underlying recordset and form controls in MS Access by name, for example:

```
 Me.ID
 MsgBox Me.ID
 Me.txtID
```

Comment: when i use that code i get an error "invalid use of property"

Comment: Where are you putting the code? In the module belonging to the form or somewhere else?

Comment: in the code for the button , Private Sub Command10_Enter()
 Me.Field1
 MsgBox Me.Field1
 Me.txtField1

End Sub

Comment: Just use one, say `MsgBox Me.ID` also, the click event is the usual one for a command button.

Comment: yes that works , can i store that id value in a variable this way ? also how come Me.ID on its own gives an error, but when you put Msgbox Me.id it works

Comment: Me.id by itself is like an unfinished sentence; it means nothing. Yes, you can assign the value of a field or control to a variable `myvar = Me.ID` or `myvar = Me.txtID.value` where txtID is the name of a control. The default property of a control is value, so you do not have to refer to the value property to get the value, but you can, if you want.

Comment: thats great i understand now , thanks alot for your responses they were very helpful to me