# Open access form to a specific record

Tags: ms-access

[VB open form on a specific record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511280/vb-open-form-on-a-specific-record).

This page has an answer, but because I am a beginner level, I do not now how to do this in Access via the macro builder.  I do not know how to write in VB yet and that seems to be the only answers I can find.

I want to open a form called Vehicles  and go to the fileno field (text and a number combined).  There I would like the user to be able to input the file number to search for (which will always change with each new search).  I know this is probably simple, but I need to get instructions in the expression builder terms.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I you created the form with the form wizzard, there is a search function at the bottom of the form between the << and >> buttons if you type down in the search, access will lead you the record containing that value no matter what field, the only problem is that is has to a exact match.